# How does the thunder network work? And how does it keep things decentralized?

Tags: lightning-network

How does the new thunder network work? How does it keep things decentralized?

Comment: Isn't Thunder just an implementation of the Lightning network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thunder Network is just an implementation of the Lightning Network, so it follows the same methods as LN. The [summary paper](https://lightning.network/lightning-network-summary.pdf) provides a good overview of how it keeps things decentralised.